# How to use dynamic column inside of bquote

Tags: r, metaprogramming, non-standard-evaluation

```r
a <- "t"
bquote(data.frame(.(a) = 1:10)
Error: unexpected '=' in "bquote(data.frame(.(a) ="
```

`a` needs to be dynamic. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: is there a reason why you have accepted so few answers to your questions?

Comment: sometimes i forget. the superfluous features and functions of stackoverflow is not a priority for me. most of the time though, the answers did not solve me problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `bquote` for this. The easiest way to solve this is just to use `setNames()`

```
a <- "t"
setNames(data.frame(1:10), a))
```

Alternative you could build the `data.frame` call and then use `do.call` but you still have to set the parameter name with `setNames()`

```
do.call("data.frame", setNames(list(1:10), a))
```

But if you are using `tidyverse` packages, you can dynamically set names in a `tibble` call using `:=`

```
tibble(!!a := 1:10)
```